# Copying text from one file to another using bash script

Tags: bash, file, copy

I am trying to copy a specific piece of text from one file to a specific space in another file (that has content) using a bash script.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "specific space in another file"?

Comment: not sure what you mean by specific space but..if you're asking about appending the content of one file to the bottom of another file..this should work: `cat source_file_name >> destination_file_name`

Comment: By specific space I mean neither top nor bottom, but a specified spot in the text.

Comment: Also, I don't want to take the whole text from the first file, I want to know how to take a specific portion. I want to specify this portion using words in the text.

Comment: Do `YOU` know how that 'specific portion' is defined? e.g. based on line numbers: x to y, delimited by some particular text markers, x_start to x_end etc...

Comment: Yes, the text is a data text full of numbers and some words. I can define the portion I want by saying, for instance, from "ti" to "*". Line number won't work because it differs from file to file. Please let me know if my question is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

To extract a portion of a file you can use sed :

```
 ## extract line 12 to 13 of file.txt
 sed "12,13p;d" test.txt
```

So if you want to insert some lines in another file, you just have to cut the ingoing files.

For instance, inserting lines 12 to 13 of file2.txt inside file1.txt at line 15, storing the result in result.txt would be:

```
 sed '1,14p;d' file1.txt > result.txt 
 sed '12,13p;d' file2.txt >> result.txt 
 sed '15,$p;d' file1.txt >> result.txt
```

That being said, you can also consider using an `ed` script to achieve the same thing

```
  echo -e '14r !sed "12,13p;d" file2.txt\nw' | ed -s file1.txt
```